# Java Callable Pool thread do it all on this same time

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

Hi I have some probleme with thread. I want to do one method for n thread and I don't know how do it. do it this : I have list of new objects which look like this :
I create a class(1) which implements a interface Callable I use this because callable thread don't return void. Next I have a list of string(url) Next I create a list of object look like class (1) . next i create a executor and i want to do thread on my list of obcject n-thread

```
public class UtlToImageConverter implements Callable<BufferedImage> {

    private String url;
    private static BufferedImage image;

    public UtlToImageConverter(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        getImgFromPath(url);
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        UtlToImageConverter.image = image;
    }

    public static BufferedImage getImgFromPath(String path){
        if(TestURLImage4.imgCache.get(path) != null){
            return TestURLImage4.imgCache.get(path);
        }
        else{
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(path);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(TestURLImage4.imgCache.size());
            TestURLImage4.imgCache.put(path, image);
            return image;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedImage call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("url  "  +url);
        getImgFromPath(url);
        System.out.println("url ok "  +url);
        return image;
    }

}
```

Next i do it this :

```
ArrayList<UtlToImageConverter> threadList = new ArrayList<>(); 
            for(String url : URLPathList){
                threadList.add(new UtlToImageConverter(url));
            }
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        try {
//          executor.invokeAll(threadList, 1000L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            executor.invokeAll(threadList);
//          executor.invokeAny(threadList);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
//      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Though you forgot to ask a question, you obviously have two main problems here: (1) your thread pool only has one thread, you need more to execute tasks in parallel, change `1` to the actual number of threads you'd like to use in the `newFixedThreadPool()` call. (2) You need to use `invokeAll()` to be sure all your tasks are executed and finished; `invokeAny()` executes all tasks but only waits for one of them to be finished and then cancels the others.

Comment: @AndrewLygin Ok I change to this   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); But if i have number 1 or 2 or 10 it work this same

Comment: @AndrewLygin Changed number of newFixedThreadPool don't changed time

Comment: It works the same because you're calling `ivokeAny()`. It executes one task and stops. You need `invokeAll()`. But it will not necessarily change the time, it will only do more work that will either take the same time or even more time. But at least, all your images will be downloaded. Now, you only download one image.

Comment: @AndrewLygin I changed to this : executor.invokeAll(threadList, 1000l, TimeUnit.MINUTES); But it don't change anything

Comment: @AndrewLygin  If i have 1 or 10 thread now it works this same

Comment: What do you mean by "works the same". What messages does the program print? How many items do you have in `URLPathList`?

Comment: @AndrewLygin in URLPathList i have 256 items, when I have for e.x. 1 thread pool this proces takes 31 seconds , when I have 10 thread pool the proces takes 31 seconds . I edit code now You see what I have

Comment: Do you see the messages "url ..." and "url ok ..."? Do you see that they are working in parallel? Try to use `System.out.println(String.format("%d: URL %s", Thread.currentThread().getId(), "abc"))` instead of `System.out.println("url  "  +url)`. Do you see different thread ids?

Comment: @AndrewLygin result :  29: URL abc
30: URL abc
31: URL abc
38: URL abc
36: URL abc
34: URL abc
29: URL abc
33: URL abc
30: URL abc
31: URL abc
33: URL abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call `getImgFromPath()` from the constructor of `UtlToImageConverter`. So, all the images are downloaded in the process of instantiation, sequentially, before being submitted to the executor. The executor just retrieves them from the cache, so you don't see the difference. Remove the `getImgFromPath()` call from the constructor and let the executor do the actual downloading.

Comment: could you tell me how it must look like. Because I don't know how I can do it

Comment: Just remove the line `getImgFromPath();` from the constructor (it's the 8th line in your code).

Comment: I do what You said I remove this line from contructor but if i have 1 thread pool or 10 or 20 or 100 the time still is this same

Comment: That's strange because this code works for me. Maybe, it's the web-server that is processing your requests cannot do it in parallel? Do all the urls point to the same server?

Comment: Try to feed to the program URLs from different web-servers and see if it works. I tried ten urls from different services and 1, 3 or 10 threads. The difference was obvious.

Comment: Ok that's hel. Thank you for help :-)